# Cannot get Active-HDL to run in Lattice Diamond

Tags: lattice

I have the latest version of Lattice Diamond installed and a freshly generated Free license. However, when I try to run a simulation, I get an a window that says "FLEXlm not initialized.".

After about two hours of mucking around on the next, I have not yet found a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full reinstall of Diamond, everything started working.